# Is it possible to downgrade version of Visual Studio For Mac? [Due to an error with Hot Reload]

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-mac, hot-reload

After the last update, VS for Mac Hot Reload stopped working. This greatly stops my work and the work of my team. Already contacted Microsoft Support, but did not receive any response. (Only stackoverflow provided an answer that will be updated soon. However, it has been a week since the problem and no solutions)

I read a lot of forums and requests from other users in which the same problem, but nowhere is fixed. So the only way out is downgrade VS for Mac, maybe someone knows if it's possible?

Thanks

Comment: You can seek better support from Developer community : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=41.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to install a [virtual machine](https://www.macworld.co.uk/feature/best-virtual-machine-software-3671133/) on your mac environment and run it from there as an interim solution?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).